# Отображение выбранного значения при рендеринге формы в django

Tags: python, django, form

У меня имеется следующая форма (forms.py):

```
class SummarySearchForm(forms.Form):
    area = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label="Регион",
            queryset=City.objects.all().select_related("parent_city"),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.Select
        )
```

И во views.py:

```
form = SummarySearchForm(request.data)
```

При этом в форме отображается весь список городов с сортировкой из модели **City**.
Мне необходимо, чтобы так же отображался весь список городов, но при рендере поля было по умолчанию задано мое значение.
Вот такой код не работает (добавлено поле initial):

```
class SummarySearchForm(forms.Form):
    area = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label="Регион",
            queryset=City.objects.all().select_related("parent_city"),
            required=False,
            initial=City.objects.get(hh_catalog_city_id=1661),
            widget=forms.Select
        )
```

Ожидалось, что будет список, с уже выбранной нужной областью, но при этом была бы возможность выбрать любую другую.
Прошу помочь решить мой вопрос. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось реализовать функционал следующим образом:

```
if request.data == {}:
    form = SummarySearchForm(initial={"area": City.objects.get(hh_catalog_city_id=1661)})
else:
    form = SummarySearchForm(request.data)
```

В целом, выглядит как костыль. Возможно причина в том, что у меня эта вьюха (функция) работает сразу с GET и POST запросами. Возможно удалось бы этого избежать, если бы вьюха была в виде класса, где каждый вид запроса обрабатывался бы в своей функции.